# Inner Product on Linear Space of Continuous Functions

Tags: linear-algebra, continuity, inner-products

Consider the linear space of continuous functions $C[-1,+1]$ defined over the interval $[-1,+1]$. We define an inner product $\langle\cdot , \cdot\rangle$ on $C[-1,+1]$ by

$$\langle f,g\rangle=\int_{-1}^{+1} f(x)\cdot g(x) \, d(x),$$

for any $f,g$ in $C[-1,+1]$.

1) Consider the linear sub-space $V=\operatorname{Span}(x, x^2)$ in $C[-1,+1]$. Find an orthonormal basis of $V$.

2) Consider the projection $\operatorname{Proj}_V:\,C[-1,+1]\rightarrow V$. Use the orthonormal basis obtained in 1) to calculate $\operatorname{Proj}_V(x^3)$.

---

I get that $\langle x,x^2\rangle =\int_{-1}^{+1} x^3\,dx=0$, but I'm not sure what the dimension of an orthonormal basis would be. $2\times 2$?

Comment: 1)Hint: what's $\int_{-1}^{1}(ax)\cdot (bx)^2dx$?

Comment: Please don't write $<f,g>$.  I changed it to $\langle f,g\rangle$. ${}\qquad{}$